# Create a html fanapp application with wordpress for android?

Tags: android, html, wordpress

I have seen a lot of fan applications on google play. They seem to be HTML5 running on a webview. They show a list of videos, images and information (Seem like RSS) about a subject. Do anybody know if they could be easily done with worpress? I know wordpress comes with some built-in mobile views, but I'm openend to move to any other technology to accomplish this. What really amazed me is how easily is to show/retrieve content to the user through this kind application when you have a little framework based on Wordpress or any other CMS.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is use the REST Api that wordpress provides.

Here is a link to the documentation: http://developer.wordpress.com/docs/api/

Comment: Yes, but what about to get the vids, etc... from a subject. Is there any way to find all the stuff some way? I have been looking around without any luck.